# Preciso de ajuda para retornar dados

Tags: php, laravel, api, for

Olá, sou bastante novo na área e estou fazendo um pequeno projeto.
Quero retornar todos as parcelas de um aluno com um loop for mas ele retorna apenas o último item do array, alguém pode me ajudar?

ParcelaController

```
  public function store(ParcelaRequest $request)
{
    $request->validated();
    $data = new Carbon($request->data_vencimento);

    $valor = $request->valor_curso / $request->qtd_parcelas;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $request->qtd_parcelas; $i++) {



        $parcelas = [
            'aluno_id'        => $request->aluno_id,
            'matricula_id' => $request->matricula_id,
            'num_parcela'     => $i,
            'valor_parcela'   => $valor,
            'data_vencimento'=> $data->addMonths(1),
        ];
        
    }
    return response()->json([
         $parcelas
    ], 200);
}
```

[retorno da api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqBpq.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O problema é que a cada iteração do loop você está sobrescrevendo o valor da variável `$parcelas`.

Fiz algumas alterações no seu código:

```php
public function store(ParcelaRequest $request)
{
    $request->validated();
    $data = new Carbon($request->data_vencimento);

    $valor = $request->valor_curso / $request->qtd_parcelas;
    $parcelas = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $request->qtd_parcelas; $i++) {

        $parcelas[] = [
            'aluno_id'        => $request->aluno_id,
            'matricula_id' => $request->matricula_id,
            'num_parcela'     => $i,
            'valor_parcela'   => $valor,
            'data_vencimento'=> $data->addMonths(1),
        ];

        /*
        $parcelas = [
            'aluno_id'        => $request->aluno_id,
            'matricula_id' => $request->matricula_id,
            'num_parcela'     => $i,
            'valor_parcela'   => $valor,
            'data_vencimento'=> $data->addMonths(1),
        ];
        */
    }
    return response()->json($parcelas, 200);

    /*
    return response()->json([
         $parcelas
    ], 200);*/
}
```

Ao colocar os colchetes após a variável você está dizendo ao PHP: **essa variável é um array, adicione o valor que está à esquerda do sinal de = ao final do array.**

Assim, a cada iteração do loop, você terá os valores adicionados ao array `$parcelas`.

Comment: muito obrigado! consegui fazer funcionar

Comment: Se a resposta te ajudou, selecione ela como aceita para que outros possam saber que sua questão foi resolvida.